# NSNull returns <null> instead of returning null

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnull

I'm using the following code to   check if a NSNumber has nil value. So I'm converting the NSNumber to string and Im checking if its length is 0. If it is of zero, Im returning NSNull else Im returning the number itself.

```
   - (id)NSNullToNilForKey:(NSNumber *)number
    {
        if ([[number stringValue] length] == 0){
            return [NSNull null];
        }
        return number;
    }
```

Im invoking it as follows,

```
NSString *bodyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[ \"%@\",{\"session_token\": \"%@\",\"request\": [\"GetAssigneeWiseCompliancesChart\",{\"country_id\": %@,\"business_group_id\": %@,\"legal_entity_id\": %@,\"division_id\": %@,\"unit_id\": %@,\"user_id\": %@}]}]",clientSessionId,clientSessionId,[self NSNullToNilForKey:countryId],[self NSNullToNilForKey:businessGroupId],[self NSNullToNilForKey:legalEntityId],[self NSNullToNilForKey:divId],[self NSNullToNilForKey:unitId], [self NSNullToNilForKey:userId]];
```

But the problem is that, though the if loop is getting invoked. The value returned from the if loop of NSNullToNilForKey is `<null>` instead of `null`. How can I sort this out?

Comment: what is means `if loop is getting invoked the valu`

Comment: i have updated my question

Comment: may I know why you want to pass the null in to server

Comment: if the user has not selected a legal entity or a division, their specific id has to be null when Im passing it to the server

Comment: pass the empty value , it automtically converted to empty or null

Comment: if i pass an empty value , it is `(null)` and not null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a string from a format, all of the parameters are added by taking their description, what you're seeing is the description of the `NSNull` instance.

Your method should specifically return a string and you should choose explicitly what string you want to return.

```
- (id)NSNullToNilForKey:(NSNumber *)number
{
    if ([[number stringValue] length] == 0){
        return @"NSNull";
    }
    return number;
}
```

Comment: is there by anymeans that I could insert NSNull instead of <null>?

Comment: You already are returning that instance, but you can't change the description it returns, you need to return a string instead

Comment: Ca you please explain with reference to my code? Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to return that string but I've updated the answer

Comment: It works. Thank you. I replaced @"NSNull" with "null"

Answer (score 0):

try this

change the type anyobject `id` to `NSNumber *`

```
 - (NSNumber *)NSNullToNilForKey:(NSNumber *)number
{
    if ([[number stringValue] length] == 0){
        return [NSNull null];
    }
    return number;
}
```